# Our hot water heater is gas, and it only has low med. and high temperature settings. Which setting is the safest to use for our home?

Tags: plumbing

Our hot water tank is gas, and only has high, med, and low temperature settings. Which one is the safest setting for our single home?

Answer (score 1):

Start at medium, or at the current setting, if you already have it connected.

Go to the nearest hot water faucet, let the faucet run for 3 or 4 minutes.

Put a thermometer into the stream of water. NOTE, your finger is not a thermometer.

If the temp is higher than 115F, then your heater is set too high.

If the temp is under 100F, it will feel warm at best in the shower, it is too low.

---

In a perfect world, you have a mixing or tempering valve. This lets you mix some cold water with the water coming out of the heater, allowing you to get 'baby bear' temperature - just right.

Comment: In fact, it's common these days to install a thermostatic tempering valve right at the water heater, and run a highly-insulated tank somewhat above 115 F and mix it down to the desired temperature. That delivers hot-enough water longer for a given tank size, and may be mote efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, this advice is too low -- you need to run the tank at a good 127-130F to avoid coming home after vacation to find that some [*Legionella pneumophilia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legionella_pneumophila) have decided to hold a party in your hot water system!

Comment: @keshlam -- also, tempering valves belong at the *point of use* to avoid a stagnant leg of warm water in the plumbing system.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: In a typical home system, the hot water pipes _frequently_ cool far below that point, since there is no recirculating system. Tempering at source doesn't make that any worse, and tempering at point of use doesn't make it any better. Your advice might make sense for a hotel or apartment building which can afford to spend energy on keeping the entire system heated, but...

Answer (score 1):

Use a thermometer, but you want to make sure that you have temperatures in the 125-130degF range for your untempered hot water (it sounds scalding hot, but cooler temperatures promote the growth of nasties like [*L. pneumophilia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legionella_pneumophila) in your hot water system).

Tempering valves, by the way, belong at the point of use -- this prevents stagnant legs of warm water from serving as points where bacteria can grow.

Comment: Uhm... Having the tempering valve at the tank is (still) no more dangerous than an old-style installation with thermostat only and no tempering valve.

Answer (score 0):

If you have children and none of the faucets have an anti scald temperature mixing valve then go with with medium.  if you have children and do have an anti scald temperature mixing valve then go with hot.  If you do NOT  have children then go with hot.

Answer (score 0):

120f to 140f is recommended 120f like the person said to avoid bacteria growth and 140 or under to not get burned, scald risk starts above 120f.

Comment: This Answer could use some supporting documentation or reasoning. You may be correct, but since there are no citations or references it's like asking us to just trust you. You could [edit] this answer to provide more information, and be sure to take the [tour] to read about how to form a great Answer.